# docker-compose sonarqube and PostgreSQL in Azure App Service

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, sonarqube, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to make a docker compose file that include a sonarqube and a Postgre database, and deploy it to Azure App service.

Below is the docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: postgres
     volumes:
       - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
       - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     restart: always
     environment:
       POSTGRES_USER: sonar
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar

   sonarqube:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: sonarqube
     ports:
       - "9000:9000"
     volumes:
       - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
       - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
       - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
       - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins
     restart: always
     environment:
       SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
       SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
       SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar

volumes:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
```

in my local machine, everything is working as expected and I can access Sonarqube. However, once I try to apply the docker-compose file in Azure App service I got the following entries in the log :

[image]

I tried to check if I can increase vm.max_map_count in App service, but I didn't find a way to do so.

How can I resolve this issue ? and is there at least a way to bypass this bootstrap check of vm.max_map_count ?

Comment: Could you please check here https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/ It is mentioned here, you can disable the feature by adding a property in sonar.properties Please go through this, it might help you.

Comment: I created a sonarqube image overriding some values in sonar.properties. But it seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to increase `vm.max_map_count` in Azure App Service. You can bypass this bootstrap check by adding the following line in the environment variables section of the SonarQube service:

```
SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE: 'true'
```